# Setting Environment with Puppet and test it with TravisCI

Tags: github, puppet, travis-ci

I want to use TravisCI for testing pull requests for my github repo. But i use puppet for setting environment and installing dependencies. Is there any way to build dependencies with puppet in `.travis.yml`.

Comment: Can you not include puppet setup in your Rakefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [customize the build environment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/) by writing a shell script that installs and runs puppet.